# Convert string into instruction in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I would like to use a string in Angular HTML to eval my `ngIf`:

```
ts:
stringToEval:string = "element.users.length > 0"
elements: Element[] = [
   {
     name: 'name1', 
     users: []
   },{
     name: 'name2',
     users: [
       user: 'user1',
       user: 'user2'
     ]
 }];
html:

 <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements;">
     <div *ngIf="!stringToEval"> 
         element.users is empty
     </div>
     <div *ngIf="stringToEval"> 
         element.users has element
     </div>               
 </ng-container>
```

Maybe a pipe is  what I need to do? But is it possible to call a pipe in a `ngIf`? I tried it and it crashes.

Comment: What is the question? You want `element.users.length > 0` to be evaluated in `*ngIf`? JavaScripts `eval()` can do that, but it's evil from a security perspective.

Comment: I want to use something like Javascript eval but in html code

Comment: Have you tried it? If it doesn't work, you can try to add a function to your component that calls eval or add it to a pipe as you suggested in your question already.

Comment: [check this](https://angular-q9cgwz.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 0):

You need a boolean. Let me explain you in very simple code.

val:boolean;

```
if(element.users.length > 0) {
 val = true;
} else val = false;
```

and in the HTML you can check it like:

```
<div *ngIf="val">Hello</div>
```

It will render Hello if val is true and if it's false then it will not show it.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate it like so:

```
<div *ngIf="element.users.length">
    element.users is empty
</div>
<div *ngIf="!element.users.length">
    element.users has element
</div>
```

**[Remember that javascript evaluates a 0 as `false`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp)**.